# How can I make a numpy ndarray from network binary image bytes?

Tags: python-3.x, image, numpy, opencv, multidimensional-array

Backgroup:

> I want to  tranfer the binary bytes image to python services from other services with grpc protocol. and the python service will handle the image in opencv lib.  I download the image from other serivces and send image data from memory to python services.

The question is how to efficiently convert binary bytes image to opencv in python.?

before python services.
It read image from local path.  the type of img is **numpy.ndarray**

```py
  img = cv2.imread(img_path)
  img = cv2.resize(img, (224,224))
```

I wish be that as follow, and how to implement **convert** function efficiently and simply!

```py
   img = convert(image)  #image is the binary bytes image from grpc protocol
   img = cv2.resize(img, (224,224))
```

here some similar problem. but it read data from local and convert to opencv.

ref:

- [Python OpenCV load image from byte string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170752/python-opencv-load-image-from-byte-string)
- [How can I make a numpy ndarray from bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47637758/how-can-i-make-a-numpy-ndarray-from-bytes/55799548)

note: I am newer to python

**the version of python is python3**

Answer (score 1):

Since most services receive an image with a byte string there is a way to efficiently convert it to numpy format

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

def convert(byte_str):
  image_np = np.from_buffer(byte_str, dtype=np.uint8) # Get a 1d-array of an image
  return cv2.imdecode(image_np, cv2. IMREAD_COLOR) # Gets back a numpy array

img = convert(image)
```